# Javascript function call without defined parameters?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, socket.io, callback

I'm new to javascript and have been following this tutorial series on how sockets work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZWmrt3Jy10.

He writes:

```
var io = socket(server);
io.sockets.on('connection', newConnection);

function newConnection(socket){
    console.log('new connection' + socket.id);
}
```

How does newConnection work in the sockets.on? It needs a socket parameter yet it works, it is a reference to the function as well. I have heard of callbacks vaguely but am still confused. Can someone please explain what is happening.

Comment: could you understand this : io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){newConnection(socket)});

Comment: `io.sockets.on('connection', newConnection);` is the same as `io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){ console.log('new connection' + id); });`. The function is just extracted and referenced by name.

Answer (score 1):

Functions in Javascript are "first class" objects and they can be passed around, stored in variables etc... consider this simple example:

```
function foo(x) {
    console.log("foo(" + x + ") called");
}

function bar(f) {
    f(42);
}

bar(foo);
```

last line calls the function `bar` passing it as a parameter the function `foo`. The function `bar` then calls the function `f` that it received passing `42` as argument.

The net result will be the message `foo(42) called` appearing in console.

In the code you show what happens is that the `on` function will store away the argument to call it later (providing the socket as parameter) once a connection is established.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing your function so the `socket.on` method just like you would be passing a variable. And just like a variable, the code inside `socket.on` can then use your function including passing you the required parameter.

The `socket.on()` method would be implemented something like this:

```
Socket.prototype.on = function (event, callback) {
    // other logic
    callback(socket); // pass socket to your newConnection function
}
```

So when you call:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', newConnection);
```

you are passing your function `newConnection` as a callback (this can be named anything by the programmer who wrote `socket.on`) and then it will call your function as:

```
callback(socket); // callback is second parameter so
                  // in your case it is pointing to
                  // newConnection
```

so it passes the socket to your function.

Comment: Thanks, so am I right in thinking that any callback will take the object as an argument?

Comment: It depends on the programmer who wrote the `socket.on` function how he will call your callback. So you need to read the documentation to figure out how he expects the callback to be. For example, the callback to `Array.reduce()` takes two arguments - the accumulator and the current item, the callback to `setTimeout()` takes no arguments etc.